# How do I create new option if there are no left while searching in React-Select v2?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I need to create new option with label "Ostatni" while filtering if there are no options left. I tried to do it by customising **MenuList** and **NoOptionsMessage**, but nothing works. Is there any way?

```
NoOptionsMessage = props => (
    <components.NoOptionsMessage
        {...props}
        children={<components.Option {...components.Option.defaultProps} data={{ value: 37, label: 'Ostatni' }} />}
    />
)
```

Comment: Please, give us some code

Comment: @KolaCaine Added

Comment: If no option available, you want to call an option with a label : "Ostatni" ?
Where come from your component ? From library ? Or it's your own component ?

Comment: component.Option comes from React-Select library. 
https://react-select.com/components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your goal using `filterOption` function like the following code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hasExtraValue: false,
      options: [
        { label: "Label 1", value: 1 },
        { label: "Label 2", value: 2 },
        { label: "Label 3", value: 3 },
        { label: "Label 4", value: 4 },
        { label: "Label 5", value: 5 },
        { label: "Label 6", value: 6 },
        { label: "Label 7", value: 7 },
        { label: "Label 8", value: 8 },
        {label: 'Ostatni', value: 'other'}
      ]
    };
  }
  filterOption = (option, inputValue) => {
    // tweak the filterOption to render Ostatni only if there's no other option matching + set hasExtraValue to true in case you want to display an message
    if (option.label === "Ostatni"){
      const {options} = this.state
      const result = options.filter(opt => opt.label.includes(inputValue))
      this.setState({ hasExtraValue: !result.length})
       return !result.length
       };

    return option.label.includes(inputValue);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Select
          isMulti
          filterOption={this.filterOption}
          noOptionsMessage={() => "No more options"}
          options={this.state.options}
        />
        // Displays a user friendly message to explain the situation
        {this.state.hasExtraValue && <p>Please select 'Ostatni' option if you don't find your option !</p>}
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The idea is to trigger when the user is typing something. If there's no options available you add a new one the desired label to offer the user a new option.

In `filterOption` you set this special option to be always `true` so it will always displayed if it exists.

[Here a live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/m53yq1718j).

Comment: I might not said it clearly, but I need selectable option "Ostatni" in the situation there are no other options left. :/

Comment: One last thing. I meant that i need option "ostatni" while filtering. So instead of seeing "No more options" I need to see "Ostatni" option. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: It disappears. But that's not the problem, I have everything else handled

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185323/discussion-between-laura-and-honza-sedlo).

Answer (score 0):

This now seems possible through a built-in component.

[image]

https://react-select.com/creatable

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import CreatableSelect from 'react-select/creatable';
import { colourOptions } from '../data';

export default class CreatableSingle extends Component<*, State> {
  handleChange = (newValue: any, actionMeta: any) => {
    console.group('Value Changed');
    console.log(newValue);
    console.log(`action: ${actionMeta.action}`);
    console.groupEnd();
  };
  handleInputChange = (inputValue: any, actionMeta: any) => {
    console.group('Input Changed');
    console.log(inputValue);
    console.log(`action: ${actionMeta.action}`);
    console.groupEnd();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <CreatableSelect
        isClearable
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
        options={colourOptions}
      />
    );
  }
}
```