# React-select default value when no options match with the user search value

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have an array for react-select like as below

```
[{label:"blue",value:"blue"},{label:"green",value:"green"},{label:"other",value:"other"}]
```

When an user tries to search other than blue and green,(like brown, purple) the other option should be shown in the options list, so the user can select the "other"

Is there any way to achieve this functionality in react-select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is close from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53788057/how-do-i-create-new-option-if-there-are-no-left-while-searching-in-react-select/53799454#53799454).

Basically use a `filterOption` props like this:

```
 filterOption = (option, inputValue) => {
    if (option.label === "Other") {
      const { options } = this.state;
      const result = options.filter(opt => opt.label.includes(inputValue));
      this.setState({ hasExtraValue: !result.length });
      return !result.length;
    }

    return option.label.includes(inputValue);
  };
```

Here's a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactselect-v2-filteroptions-8wyl9) matching your requirements.

Comment: Thank you  it worked . CodeSandBox link helped me more.

Comment: Thanks for providing the example of filterOption, because the documentation doesn't give clear example of this props. By default, when searching, the filter is based on both properties of the data object : value and label. Let's say, I have an data object that consist of fields : personId and personName. I want to assign personId to the value property, while personName to the label property. The default filter may give undesired result when typing in certain input value, because it may be contained in the value property rather than in the label property. So the filterInput props solve this.

Answer (score 1):

A small problem with the above solution.
The search becomes case sensitive. To solve is simple:

```
filterOption = (option, inputValue) => {

const inputValueToUpperCase = inputValue.toUpperCase();

   if (option.label === "Other") {
      const { options } = this.state;
      const result = options.filter(opt => opt.label.toUpperCase().includes(inputValueToUpperCase));
      this.setState({ hasExtraValue: !result.length });
      return !result.length;
   }

   return option.label.toUpperCase().includes(inputValueToUpperCase);
}
```

That way it fits. I hope to help other people.

Here's a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-v2-filteroptions-x5h8q) matching your requirements.